# Why can't I reassign the size of an array by replacing the variable with an array of different size?

Tags: java, arrays, size

This is my first post here, so please be friendly! :)

Let's say I have this code:

```
public static void reassign (int[] nums) {
  int[] A = {10,11,22};
  A = nums;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] nums = {0,2};

  reassign(nums);
  System.out.println(nums[1]);
}
```

Why is my answer 2, and not 11? Does it have something to do with the relative sizes of the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is my answer 2, and not 11?

For one, you wanted to write

```
public static void reassign (int[] nums) {
  int[] A = {10,11,22};
  nums = A;
}
```

But than won't help you either: you cannot assign to one method's local variable from another method. The *value* of the variable (a reference to the array) is passed to `reassign`, not the *address* of the variable itself.

In `reassign` you merely create a new array and then assign its reference to the local variable `nums` (in my corrected code).

> Does it have something to do with the relative sizes of the arrays?

No, the reason behind it is fully general and applies to all of Java.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this,

```
public static void reassign (int[] nums) {
    int[] A = {10,11,22};
    A = nums;
}
```

you make `A` as a refference of `nums`, and the `nums` you are refering to is the one from parameter, not the one from main method. its two different variable

This is how you suppose to do it:

```
static int[] nums = {0,2}; //initial value of nums

public static void reassign (int[] arr) {
    nums=arr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = {10,11,22};
    System.out.println("before reassign:"+nums[1]);
    reassign(A);
    System.out.println("after reassign:"+nums[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
    before reassign:2
    after reassign:11
```